# [freenect.launch] is neither a launch file in package [freenect_launch] nor is [freenect_launch]

Tags: ros, kinect, installation, freenect-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to get the Kinect working with ROS.
I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreenect-dev
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-freenect-launch
```

Which works perfectly fine.
Then:

```
roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch
```

I get:

```
 [freenect.launch] is neither a launch file in package [freenect_launch] nor is [freenect_launch] a launch file name
```

Even though it installed without a problem.
Can anyone help please?
I am using ROS-Jade if that matters, but

```
sudo apt-get install ros-jade-freenect-launch
```

does not seem to exist.

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-freenect-launch
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217439/%5Bfreenect.launch%5D-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package-%5Bfreenect_launch%5D-nor-is-%5Bfreenect_launch%5D/) by [Ardjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23827/ardjan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-freenect-launch
> ```

Looking at [ros.org/debbuild/jade.html?q=freenect](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/jade.html?q=freenect) and [wiki.ros.org/freenect_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/freenect_launch), it would appear that that package just hasn't been released yet for Jade.

> Even though it installed without a problem. Can anyone help please? I am using ROS-Jade if that matters, [..]

Yes, it matters. You installed `freenect_launch` for Indigo (ros-**indigo**-freenect-launch), but are trying to use it in Jade. That won't work, as the package hasn't been installed there, as you found out.

I don't use the packages, so I don't know whether this is possible (or what is holding up a Jade release), but you could try building the packages from source in a Jade catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ardjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23827/ardjan/) on 2015-09-11**:
Thank you!

I feel silly now, I will uninstall and install indigo (the version of ROS doesn't really matter to me) and hopefully that will work.